# incoming SMTP not getting to my Azure VM Windows server 2012 C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop

Tags: windows, email, iis, smtp, azure

This worked until November 2016.
Then, I shutdown the VM to save money because I didn't need it for awhile.
This year 2017 I restarted VM ok, but now SMTP is received, according to Wireshark and the SMTP log below, but incoming doesn't go to C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\ folder.

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\SMTPSVC1\ ...

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-05-05 15:30:19
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
15:30:19 69.78.67.195 EHLO - 250
15:30:19 69.78.67.195 MAIL - 250
15:30:19 69.78.67.195 RCPT - 550
15:30:24 69.78.67.195 QUIT - 240
15:36:56 69.78.67.197 EHLO - 250
15:36:56 69.78.67.197 MAIL - 250
15:36:56 69.78.67.197 RCPT - 550
15:37:02 69.78.67.197 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-05-05 16:09:34
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
16:09:34 69.78.67.203 EHLO - 250
16:09:34 69.78.67.203 MAIL - 250
16:09:34 69.78.67.203 RCPT - 550
16:09:39 69.78.67.203 QUIT - 240
16:21:11 69.78.67.195 EHLO - 250
16:21:11 69.78.67.195 MAIL - 250
16:21:11 69.78.67.195 RCPT - 550
16:21:16 69.78.67.195 QUIT - 240
```

Comment: `16:21:11 69.78.67.195 RCPT - 550` - SMTP code 550 usually signifies an invalid recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that my DNS provider changed my email domain name.
I fixed it:
IIS6 > SMTP Virtual ..  >  Domains  >  Domain Name:  add missing email domain name